# How to move Android Soft Keyboard to top part of the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

The default action for EditText in android is that the soft-keyboard pops up below the text box currently active. But my bottom part (25%) is covered by phone holder for an experimental setup, and hence the keyboard is not visible.

Is there a way to move the soft-keyboard to the top part of the screen programmatically?

Comment: Not from an app. If you control the firmware, there might be some way to do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare so there is no easy way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do this at all from an app.

Comment: @CommonsWare it should be such that the soft-keyboard appears on the top part of the screen rather than the bottom. Hardcoding it somehow will also work. Would be highly grateful for any pointers for this. Thank you.

Comment: "it should be such that the soft-keyboard appears on the top part of the screen rather than the bottom" -- the OS controls where the soft keyboard appears. Apps do not. If you are doing this project for custom hardware, you might be able to modify the OS to offer the sort of control that you are looking for.

Comment: @CommonsWare got it. Thank you, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your use case but there are plenty of hack through comming to my mind

If you need a way to overcome your own setup, then you can use floating keyboard from GBoard settings, or you can connect to your phone using scrcpy and type with your laptop's keyboard, or use a bluetooth keyboard/mouse

If you want to create an special device for some use cases, you can change the OS source code, or add a default floating keyboard to it or even attach a keyboard to that device, also you probably can change the physical design I guess